# Evaluating $2^i$

Tags: complex-numbers

It is obvious that we should use Euler's formula, but the fact that $\Vert e^{i \alpha} \Vert = 1$ (while the base is 2) brings difficulty of using it.

Can anyone think of a way evaluate this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fix a branch of the complex logarithm, and just notice that $2^i = \exp{i \log 2}$.

Comment: what did you mean by "evaluating" ? to show it in the polar form?

Comment: Have you tried doing any research? [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ei) literally returns $2^i=\cos(\log(2))+i\sin(\log(2))$, not to mention that Google will give you the decimal form.

Comment: $2^i=e^{i\ln(2)}=e^{i(\ln(2)+2\pi i n)}=e^{-2\pi n}e^{i\ln(2)}=e^{-2\pi n}(\cos(\ln(2))+i\sin(\ln(2)))$, where the first $\ln(2)$ represents any logarithm of $2$, while all others represent the real valued logarithm of $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $z^a=e^{a\log(z)}$ so we have

$$\begin{align}
e^{i\log(2)} &= e^{i(\ln\!|2+0i|+i\arg z)} \\
&= e^{i(\ln2+i(2k\pi))} \\
&=e^{i\ln2-2k\pi} \qquad k\in\Bbb{Z} \\
\end{align}$$