# From Sophie Germain's Identity to difficult integrals: the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1\cos\left((x+y)^2+y^2\right)dxdy$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

Yesterday I was interested in the so-called Sophie Germain's Identity, see [this section of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory). I was interested in it about composite numbers. After I was thinking about different consequences of this identity. Playing I prosoposed calculate the easy $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^4+4y^4}{x^2-2xy+2y^2}dxdy,$$ and after I was interested in integrals $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f\left(\frac{x^4+4y^4}{x^2-2xy+2y^2}\right)dxdy,$$
for different functions than $f(z)=z$. For example $f(z)=\log z$, that can be solved in closed-form.

A different example was $f(z)=\cos z$, using a CAS I believe that it can not solve in closed-form.

> **Question.** Calculate in terms of series, special functions (integral functions) or well-known constants $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\cos\left((x+y)^2+y^2\right)dxdy.\tag{1}$$ **Many thanks.**

I am thinking how get an approximation of $(1)$ using calculus, thus avoid provide me hints to this purpose.

Comment: The upper limit $x=1, y=1$ meant nothing for the cosine function, so I would only expect a closed form in terms of very contrived special functions.

Comment: I accept your critic, since I've posted this question, feel free if you want ask  or study different versions. Many thanks for your attention @pisco125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notation: $C$ and $S$ are Fresnel integral.

let calculate first integrate thus we can write:

$
\int cos((x+y)^2+y)dx
$

using $u=x+y \to dx=du$
we can write it like :

$\int(cos(u+y)du$
expand trigonometric function:
$\int(cos(y^2)cos(u^2)-sin(y^2)sin(u^2))du=cos(y^2)\int cos(u^2)du-sin(y^2)\int sin(u^2)du$

calculate first and second integrals with $v={u\sqrt2 \over \sqrt \pi}$ .

and finally with a little calculate :

### $- \pi ({sin(y^2)S({\sqrt 2 (x+y) \over \sqrt \pi})-cos(y^2)C({\sqrt 2 (x+y) \over \sqrt \pi}))}\over \sqrt 2$

for the first integral .

to calculate the second one we split them and calculate them sepratly so we write :
$$
\begin{align}
\int sin(y^2)S({\sqrt 2 (x+y) \over \sqrt \pi})dy=sin(y^2)((x+y)S((x+y) \sqrt { 2 \over \pi } )+{cos((x+y)^2) \over \sqrt {2\pi}})
\end{align}
$$

and exacly like first one you can write it for second one :
$$
\begin{align}
\int cos(y^2)C({\sqrt 2 (x+y) \over \sqrt \pi})dy=cos(y^2)((x+y)C((x+y) \sqrt { 2 \over \pi } )-{sin((x+y)^2) \over \sqrt {2\pi}})
\end{align}
$$

and finally you just need to put all of this together and calculate them.

Comment: Many thanks I am going to study your answer this afternoon.

Comment: you're welcome @user243301

Comment: Go ahead and precede upright functions like $\cos$ with a backslash `\cos`, and you can use `\left` and `\right` followed by parentheses, brackets, etc. for them to automatically expand to the size of the enclosed content.

Comment: Check the edits I made to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2480227/347062) as well as the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)